# Parallel programming using pthread

Tags: c, pthreads

I have just started learning parallel programming using `pthreads`. So, for the learning purpose I tried sum of two integer arrays parallely. I have declared `struct construct` with three array variables `a`, `b` and `c`. I want to do addition of `a`, `b` and store the result in `c`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX 6

struct data {
  int a[MAX];
  int b[MAX];
  int c[MAX];
};

void *addition(void *index) {
  struct data *d1 = (struct data *)index;
  printf("value of d1 structure=%d\n", d1->a[0]);
}

int main() {
  int i, j, t;
  struct data *item = NULL;
  pthread_t threads[MAX];

  item = (struct data *)malloc(sizeof *item);

  printf("enter the value for arrray a\n");
  for (i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
    scanf("%d", &item->a[i]);
  }

  printf("enter the value of array b\n");
  for (j = 0; j < MAX; j++) {
    scanf("%d", &item->b[j]);
  }

  for (t = 0; t < MAX; t++) {
    pthread_create(&threads[t], NULL, addition, (void *)&item);
  }
}
```

Here, as of now I have not added the addition of arrays in the function `addition()`, because in `pthread_create()` when I am passing the three arguments with the help of `structure`, in function addition the variables `a` and `b` are not getting copied. Printing `a` is giving me garbage value. Can anybody help me how to copy the `structure` variable to the function argument called by `pthread_create()`.

Comment: What is the type of `item`? What is the type of `&item`? When you know that then the problem should be obvious.

Comment: You need some `pthread_join()` calls to synchronize the processing as the threads finish. You'll also need to demonstrate that the threads worked. You have not shown how your 6 different threads are doing 6 different computations. They're all doing the same computation (6 additions and assignments) without any control over access to the data. This is a major cause of (potential) trouble. You may not notice because the workload is so small that the threads never get a chance to interfere with each other. The thread function should return a value — a null pointer. Your compiler should complain!

Answer (score 3):

`pthread_create` Function  :

```
int pthread_create(pthread_t *thread, const pthread_attr_t *attr,
                          void *(*start_routine) (void *), void *arg);
```

Kindly note `(*arg)` is pointer to the `arg`.
You have created `struct data *item` as a pointer then you are passing its address i.e. pointer to pointer.

```
pthread_create(&threads[t], NULL, addition, (void *)&item);
```

Change the call to

```
pthread_create(&threads[t], NULL, addition, (void *)item).
```

Comment: changing the call to : pthread_create(&threads[t] , NULL, addition, (void *)item. worked. Problem solved. Thanks

Comment: Thank You so much